# What is type "object {string}"?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary with this definition `Dictionary<string, object>`. This dictionary gets populated with data from a form submitted to the web server.

Form fields not submitted gets what looks like an empty string set in the dictionary. E.g. if the form field `MyFormField` is not set, `myDictionary["MyFormField"]` returns `""`.

Lets say I get one one the values with what looks like an empty string from the dictionary like this:

```
var formFieldValue = formValues[formFieldName]; // Populates the formFieldValue variable with the value ""
```

Now, in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio, I run the following operations on the variable:

```
submittedFormFieldValue // => "" (just printing the value)
formFieldValue.GetType() == typeof(string) // => true
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formFieldValue) // => error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
formFieldValue.GetType() // => {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"} ...
formFieldValue == string.Empty // => false
formFieldValue == "" // => false
```

So, first I get `true` when I compare types. The I get that argument 1 cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'.

In the Watch window, the type of `formFieldValue` is shown as `object {string}`, as opposed to if I write `formFieldValue as string`, which is shown as `string`.

What is this `object {string}` type?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formFieldValue as string)`

Comment: It's really unclear in which context this is and what the types of your variables are. If you say `object foo = "bar"`, then `foo.GetType()` returns `System.String`, but you can't pass it to methods accepting a `string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At *compile-time*, the variable is of type `object` - which is why `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` fails to compile.

At *execution-time* the value of the variable is a reference to a string.

These two lines:

```cs
formFieldValue == string.Empty 
formFieldValue == ""
```

... are comparing for *reference identity* because the left operand is of type object.

I strongly suspect if you use `formFieldValue.Equals("")` then it will return `true`. Likewise if you cast to a string first:

```
string formFieldStringValue = (string) formFieldValue;
if (formFieldStringValue == "")
{
    ...
}
```

... then it will enter the body of the `if` statement, because that `==` operator uses the overloaded `==(string, string)` operator, which compares strings by text, instead of by reference identity.

Answer (score 3):

If you observe the following code, you should see similarities with the behavior you're seeing:

```
public void MyTestMethod(string s) { }

object o = "Hello StackOverflow!";

Console.WriteLine(o.GetType() == typeof(string)); // true

Console.WriteLine(o is string); // true

MyTestMethod(o); // error: cannot convert object to string
```

The important thing to notice here is that **`o` is a variable of type `object`**.

When you call `GetType`, you receive the actual type of what is contained in `o` (which is a string). Similarly, `is` looks at the actual type.

But `o` itself (not the value contained within!) is still an `object`, and thus the compiler enforces it as such.

You could avoid the compiler error by explicitly stating that the compiler should see it as a string:

```
MyTestMethod((string)o); // works
// OR
MyTestMethod(o as string); // also works
```

However, when you have to cast your variables, in most cases it meant you shouldn't have initially casted them down to a lower type (i.e. `object` instead of sticking with `string`).

I can't make that decision for you, but it may be wise to simply stop using `object` in your dictionary if you intend to only use string values. If not, then you'll be stuck having to check types (or blindly trust that you'll never write code that causes runtime exceptions - which is a bad idea for non-trivial projects).

---

The reason you're dealing with the same issue here is because your dictionary defines its values as being `object`s (because of `Dictionary<string, object>`)

```
var x = myDict["foo"];
```

If `myDict` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`, then **`x` will always be an `object`, regardless of which values you entered in the dictionary**.

For example:

```
myDict["x"] = 5;      // int
myDict["y"] = "5";    // string
myDict["z"] = 5f;     // float

var x = myDict["x"];  // object
var y = myDict["y"];  // object
var z = myDict["z"];  // object
```

Even though you can infer the type of each entry, `x` `y` and `z` will always be of type `object` since that's the type your dictionary defines its values as.

To fix that, either don't use `object` as your dictionary value type, or explicitly cast/convert your value:

```
var x = myDict["x"] as int;
var x = (int) myDict["x"];
var x = Convert.ToInt32(myDict["x"]);
```

Keep in mind that you should really be checking for parsing/casting failures here. If this is a tiny and trivial side project, you may be able to guarantee that your code is doing the right thing, but that is a dangerous and reckless approach for any decently sized project.

Comment: I don't think I can do anything about the definition of the dictionary. The data comes from a form, and the form submit is parsed by the CMS we're using. The CMS gives me the submission data as <string, object>.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `formValues` indexer returns an object, whose concrete type is a `string`.

Watch window displays them like "static type {concrete type}", which is what you are seeing.